# How to protect questions?

Tags: discussion

I have recently earned the "Protect Questions" privilege. Go me!

However I cannot find out how to actually protect a question! Not that I want to at the moment, but I might do in the future! I see that only questions older than one day can be protected- So I opened a question from a few days back and expected to see a new option next to Share, Close, Edit etc. but I could see no difference.

I did a search for "Protect Questions" but it didn't come back with *how* to do it, only what it means...

Does anyone know how?

Comment: [This question](http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/2765/4271) should show you the protect link at 3,500+ rep. Many other questions won't. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: It did, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Recent Changes Have Rendered the Documentation Incomplete

There should be a textual `protect` link next to the `flag` link at the bottom of each question, right under the question tags. However, I just noticed that the link doesn't appear for me on every question, despite the fact that the [protection privilege page](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) currently says:

> #### Which questions can be protected?
>
> Any question at least a day old can be protected and unprotected by users that have the privilege.

[An answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276978/185951) from a few weeks ago over on SE Meta that indicates that there is a system-wide undocumented change:

> 15k users will still be able to protect but in order to do so the question must have at least one answer by a new user aka a user with < 10 rep on the site (which is the required rep limit to answer protected questions).

This is probably why many questions don't currently display the `protect` link: because they haven't attracted any low-rep answers, and therefore shouldn't require protection. You might want to upvote [this related question on SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277356/185951), or otherwise chime in there to indicate that this is clearly a bug in the current Stack Exchange documentation.

Comment: Done. Thanks!!!